# Custom Bindings with Eclipse Sisu/Guice in Maven Plugins

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, guice, sisu

I've tried to add custom injection bindings to a Maven plugin, but apparently is doen't work. Somehow the "EagerSingleton"-annotated Class "MyModule" does not get initialized. But it is supposed to be initialized on container startup.

And just annotating the Module with @Named, as it is described in https://wiki.eclipse.org/Sisu/PlexusMigration#Custom_Bindings doen't work either.

The value of the "config" is not even null. It's just an empty string.

Mojo:

```
@Mojo(
    name = "echo",
    requiresProject = false
)
public class EchoMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Parameter(property = "echo.message", required = true)
    private String message;

    @Inject
    @Config
    private String config;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        logger.info(message + " / " + config);
    }
}
```

MyModule:

```
@Named
@EagerSingleton
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    public MyModule() {
        System.out.println("MyModule::init");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Config.class).to("My Value"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
}
```

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@BindingAnnotation
@Documented
public @interface Config {
}
```

Sourcecode of example: https://github.com/fripi89/maven-sisu-example

Comment: Full project best would be a link to github/gitlab etc. link etc. You seemed to be mixing several things ... Which Maven version? Source code ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using Maven version 3.6.3, Java 8. Here is the link to the example project: github.com/fripi89/maven-sisu-example.